# Issue with CRC16, UShort in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, c, kotlin

I'm having a hard time converting some C code to Kotlin/Java. The C code is the correct one. The problem is that the Kotlin code leads to a different CRC16 checksum.

This is the C code:

```c
// data_buf is of type uint8_t
uint16_t crc = 0;
for(uint32_t i = 0; i<BUF_SIZE; i++)
{
    crc += data_buf[i];
}
```

This is what I tried in Kotlin, but it does not work:

```kotlin
// DFUFile is of type ByteArray
var i = 0
var crc: UShort = 0u
while(i < DFUFile.size) {
    crc = (crc + DFUFile[i].toUShort()).toUShort()
    i += 1
}
```

I also tried the following code but it does not lead to the correct number.

```kotlin
// DFUFile is of type ByteArray
var crc = 0
var i = 0
while(i < DFUFile.size) {
     crc = (crc + DFUFile[i].toInt()) and 0x0000FFFF
     i += 1
}
```

Comment: What is the type of DFUFile and of data_buf?

Comment: Always define "doesn't work".  Because we have no idea what that means.  Does it crash, show an error, get the wrong result, etc.  Here you've cut out too much important info-  what is data_buf?  Does it point to bytes, shorts, ints, or other?  Same for DFUFile  You're trying to do byte arithmetic, types are important.

Comment: Also from the docs on toUShort-  " this value is positive and less than or equals to UShort.MAX_VALUE, the resulting UShort value represents the same numerical value as this Int."  So what does it do if the value is greater than UShort.MAX_VALUE-  if it returns the max rather than truncating that won't work at all.  You're probably better off removing all the toUShort functions and instead masking the returned value with 0x0000FFFF

Comment: Never describe a problem merely as “does not work.” Always show the observed output or behavior, the output or behavior desired instead and, if not obvious, a description of the differences. Edit the question to provide a [mre], including an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the questions.
So what happens is the calcualtion is wrong in Kotlin. I get a different number.

DFUFile is a ByteArray
data_buf is of type uint32_t

Comment: Which language, C or C++?   They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ allows overloading of operators and functions, while C doesn't.  Are you mixing C and C++? I don't recommend mixing them.  Simplify your life, pick one language and stick with it, don't mix them.

Comment: AkroB, Could `BUF_SIZE != DFUFile.size`?  For kotlin, post example data like [1, 2, 3], the sum seen and the sum expected.

Answer (score 2):

Since the C-language data_buf is of type `uint8_t[]`, your Kotlin equivalent needs to be `UByteArray`. If you can't make it a `UByteArray` for whatever reason, you can instead make each element a UByte:

```
var i = 0
var crc: UShort = 0u
while(i < DFUFile.size) {
    crc = (crc + DFUFile[i].toUByte()).toUShort()
    i += 1
}
```

or shorten it a little:

```
var crc: UShort = 0u
for (byte in DFUFile) {
    crc = (crc + byte.toUByte()).toUShort()
}
```